Cannot connect My SQL Database with FastAPI and SQL SqlAlchemy
I have just started learning about Python and FastAPI to participate in a new project, but I can't create tables or ensure that the application has connected to MySQL, is my code  or MySQL cause the issue?
File database.py  where I declare the database config
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DATABASE_URL = "mysql+pymysql://root:rorthai2002@localhost:3306/book_store"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

File Model.py  where I declare my model
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column
from database import Base



class Author(Base):
    __tablebane__ = "authors"
    id = Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    books = relationship("Book", back_populates="author")


class Book(Base):
    __tablebane__ = "books"
    id = Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    release_year = Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=True)
    author_id = Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("author.id"))

File main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI


from database import Base, engine
from schema import BookCreate


def create_tables():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def start_application():
    app = FastAPI()
    create_tables()
    return app


app = start_application()


@app.post("/books")
def create_books(book: BookCreate):
    return book


@app.get("/books")
def get_books():
    pass

My SQL server if need

It seem no table has created when I start the application
thanks a lot for helping

Since you haven't imported Model.py by the time you run Base.metadata.create_all, it doesn't know about them. Try adding import Model to your main.py file.

Can I ask a few stupid questions like, is there something wrong with the way the code is structured that leads to importing an unused module into main.py? Or does this often happen with Python imports, thanks you

Two things: 1. Right now you're  not using your database models at all. In a fuller example you'd probably use at least some of them in your API endpoints, either directly in main.py or in other files, which are in turn imported in main.py. There are real world cases where you need to import unused modules, but it should really be a last resort.


In a larger project, you don’t want to call Base.metadata.create_all in your code at all. It will work fine the first time, but not later when yoy need to add a new column, especially if you have gigabytes of data. In that case you'd use a migration tool like alembic to keep track of changes to your database structure. Then, you run your database migrations as a separate step before starting your application.

